# storing MKRoute in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, mkmapview, nskeyedarchiver

I am currently trying to store an MKRoute object in core data.  All I really need from it is the MKPolyLine so if I can store that that's fine too. I've tried using NSKeyedArchiver but that just simply throws an exception and crashes my program.  Are there any other approaches to storing an MKRoute object in a core data object (A transformable object I'd assume)?

Comment: Because MKRoute does not implement NSCoding, you would have to implement it yourself in a subclass of it. This way, you could use NSKeyedArchiver to store it as an NSData object in Core Data.

Answer (score 1):

`MKRoute` does not conform to `NSCoding` so it will fail.archiving. However you can store it in some format like KML or GeoJSON by using a third-party coder.